# How does QAbstractItemView know about my custom roles when emitting dataChanged() with no roles?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qabstracttablemodel, qabstractitemview

On receipt of the signal QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged(), the connected QAbstractItemViews will call the QAbstractItemModel::data() method to update their data. The user defined data() method should give different information based on both predefined roles like Qt::DisplayRole and any amount of user defined custom roles that should have values equivalent to Qt::UserRole and up.

With this in mind, Qt docs regarding the QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged() signal state this:

> The optional roles argument can be used to specify which data roles
>   have actually been modified. An empty vector in the roles argument
>   means that all roles should be considered modified. The order of
>   elements in the roles argument does not have any relevance.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged

In light of this, how does the QAbstractItemView know to call all my custom roles when I call dataChanged with an empty vector of roles? Or does this only refer to the predefined Qt roles?

Comment: I believe `QAbstractItemView` doesn't know what to do with the custom data you defined - it simply doesn't need it.

Comment: Whether it needs it or not surely depends on your implementation?

Comment: Let's rephrase the question: "Why view needs to process user defined roles?". All the view needs can be accessed with the standard roles, unless it's not a custom view.